# Excel c#.net retrieving data without opening excel in the background

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read a data in an excel sheet using C#, here is my code.

```
    public void ReadExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            string sheetName = "Sheet1$A1:C6";
            DataTable sheetTable = loadSingleSheet(@"C:\Users\..\Desktop\Sample.xls",                  sheetName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    private OleDbConnection returnConnection(string fileName)
    {
        return new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"");
    }
    private DataTable loadSingleSheet(string fileName, string sheetName)
    {
        DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = this.returnConnection(fileName))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // retrieve the data using data adapter
            OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
            sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
        }
        return sheetData;
    }
```

But DataTable always get null value

[image]

Comment: do you want to use Microsoft.Jet or the other third party library will do?

Comment: What is the parameter `Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;`? Try without it.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: same output

Answer (score 1):

Here it is how to do it using ODBC and ADO.Net

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
       try
       {        
            string sheetName = "Sheet1$";// Read the whole excel sheet document      
            DataTable sheetTable = loadSingleSheet(@"C:\excelFile.xls", sheetName);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sheetTable;

            string sheetNameWithRange = "Sheet1$A1:D10"; // Read excel sheet document from A1 cell to D10 cell values.
            DataTable sheetTableWithRange = loadSingleSheet(@"C:\excelFile.xls",sheetNameWithRange);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = sheetTableWithRange;
       }
       catch (Exception Ex)
       {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "");
       }  
    }        

    private OleDbConnection returnConnection(string fileName)
    {
        return new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"");
    }

    private DataTable loadSingleSheet(string fileName, string sheetName)
    {           
        DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = this.returnConnection(fileName))
        {
           conn.Open();
           // retrieve the data using data adapter
           OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
            sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
        }                        
        return sheetData;
    }
```